# Cassandra CQL: How can I SELECT token(id), * FROM table

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I would like to select all columns plus the token of the id-column:

```
SELECT token(id), * FROM table
```

This does not work; I need to manually include all the columns in my query:

```
SELECT token(id), title, message, user_id, sent_timestamp FROM table
```

Is there any shortcut in the CQL-Syntax to SELECT everything plus the token(id)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a shortcut for that.  Probably SELECT * is treated as a special case and can't be combined with other things.

If you want to generate the column names dynamically in your code instead of hardcoding them, you could retrieve them from the system tables.